# Access Vue Application on Webpack-Server in Vagrant

Tags: node.js, webpack, vagrant, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I set up a virtual machine with Vagrant, ubuntu xenial64, installed npm/nodejs and the vue-cli.

I scaffolded a webpack application with `vue init webpack myproject`. When I now run `npm run dev`the webpack server starts, but since it's inside the virtual machine I can't access the webpage on my PC.

I found out, that you can run webpack server with --host 0.0.0.0 but since the Vue-Cli generates the whole process, I wasn't able to figure out where I can add this parameter.

Or is there another solution?

Comment: do you have a `build/dev-server.js` file ? If so you can edit from there

Comment: Can't you `npm run dev` from your host machine?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I can't find the place to add this inside the file, because there is no explicit shell call to start the server. I added it to the app.listen() function, without success.

Comment: @El_Matella that's the reason why I use vagrant. We in our componany have limited admin rights, so updating npm or changing the version always requires calling our network department to give me admin rights for some hours. Having a virtual machine, I can do this more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed it myself :). Just add this to your Vagrantfile:

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 80

So nothing to do with Webpack, just basic vagrant setup. This will forward the 8080 port to 80 port of your host machine. So you need to type localhost:80 in your browser to get to your application.

Comment: I did  `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080` and it worked on mac.